# Significato di "a cofanetto"

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Tanto bello al Circolo, pensa Ninì, a starsene a chiacchierare. A pescare non c’è sfizio, pesci non se ne vedono, il sole scotta, il mare adesso nemmeno lo puoi guardare, dà male agli occhi. Fa appena in tempo a tenersi, la barca s’impenna, quel cretino di Glauco scompare **a cofanetto** in un anello di schiuma accecante.

Per si è d'aiuto, il romanzo è ambientato a Napoli.

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "a cofanetto" che appare in questo passaggio. Ho cercato alla voce "cofanetto" di parecchi dizionari, inclusi il Treccani e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione. Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare cosa vuol dire?

Ricercare "a cofanetto" su Google non è di aiuto perché appaiono molte occorrenze del tipo "scattola a cofanetto", "borsa a cofanetto", ecc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qui si tratta del tuffo a cofanetto, che si esegue portando le ginocchia al petto e stringendole tra le braccia, cercando di far schizzare molta acqua. È una traduzione in italiano dall'originale dialetto napoletano "tuffo a cufaniell".

Comment: Ah! Grazie mille, @Luciano! Veramente, ricercando  "tuffo a cufaniello" su Google se ne trovano molte spiegazioni, inclusi video e fotografie.

Comment: In napoletano sarebbe "cufaniell" o "cufaniello"? O tutte e due?

Comment: Non sono un purista del dialetto napoletano, ma noi (napoletani) tendiamo ad omettere la fine delle parole. Quindi opterei per cufaniell.

Comment: Magari sulla "tag" [tag:regional]  trovi qualche domanda per cui ti piacerebbe dare una risposta.